# Can I use Visual Studio 2010 to program Mindstorm NXT2 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I'm considering to buy mindstorm NXT2 and I'd like to know if it is possible to develop c++ software for NXT2 using Visual Studio 2010 as IDE.
I guess it will be funny to improve my C++ skills (I didn't study C, just C++) with a lego kit and in a friendly environment like Visual Studio. I know there are small online projects for NXT but I can't find nothing about NXT2....
Any suggestions would be more than welcomed

Sincerely yours

Fabio

Comment: Yes.  Ask here: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Someone is asking the same question here and received an 6 votes up answer: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/934/can-we-program-nxt2-in-c-under-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0):

My ex-boss used to program with Visual Studio 2008 with Mindstorem NXT2 with C++. He wrote a program controlling a carrier built by himself, which can move forward or backward on a track. Also it uses light sensor to detect the distance.

I think you can go ahead.

Comment: Do you know any reference that I can check to do that? I mean software, libraries...custom firmware if supported by nxt2 etcc... You know mindstorm nxt2 is quite expensive and I want to be sure that I can use it with c++ and visual studio 2010... Thanks ;)